# Listing files in two separate directories in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to get Overtone to work on my Windows 10 machine. I seem to have found a bug in the code that attempts to start the synthesizer server. Overtone depends on SuperCollider, and it looks up the location of `scsynth.exe` by looking at where SuperCollider is installed. But the code that is supposed to check both `C:\Program Files` and `C:\Program Files (x86)` only checks the first one that exists instead of both:

```
(import java.io File)
(let [p-files-dir (System/getenv "PROGRAMFILES(X86)")
      p-files-dir (or p-files-dir (System/getenv "PROGRAMFILES"))
      p-files-dir (File. p-files-dir)
      p-files     (map str (.listFiles p-files-dir))
      p-files])
```

In my case, both directories exist, but SuperCollider only exists in `C:\Program Files`. The snippet above only lists files in `C:\Program Files (x86)`.

How do I get this code to return all of the files in *both* directories, and not break when one doesn't exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were not returning something from your `let` form, so notice here `p-files` is outside the `[]`:

```
(let [p-files-dir-1 (System/getenv "PROGRAMFILES(X86)")
      p-files-dir-2 (System/getenv "PROGRAMFILES")
      p-files-dir-file-1 (File. p-files-dir-1)
      p-files-dir-file-2 (File. p-files-dir-2)
      p-files (map str (concat 
                         (.listFiles p-files-dir-file-1) 
                         (.listFiles p-files-dir-file-2)))]
  p-files)
```

The answer to your question is that you can just `concat` together two lists, after which you would need to filter for the file.

Here's a shorter answer (the `map str` is not strictly necessary here):

```
(map str (concat ["a" "b" "c"] ["d" "e" "f"]))
;; => ("a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f")
```

To remove all the temporary variables you could use this function:

```
(defn env-files [file-name]
  (some-> file-name
          System/getenv
          File.
          .listFiles))
```

Then the code becomes:

```
(map str (concat
             (env-files "PROGRAMFILES(X86)")
             (env-files "PROGRAMFILES")))
```

Comment: Perfect! I'm really surprised that `(some->` handles invalid environment vars correctly.